# Can't fix the problem with C# Windows Forms project

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<Dog> dogs;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dogs = new List<Dog>();
        }

        private void btnAddDog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name = txtName.Text;
            int age = int.Parse(txtAge.Text);

            Dog newDog = new Dog { Name = name, Age = age };
            dogs.Add(newDog);

            MessageBox.Show("Dog added successfully!");
        }

        private void btnBark_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Dog dog in dogs)
            {
                dog.Bark();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Dog
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public void Bark()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Woof woof!");
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> CS1061 "Form1" does not contain a definition of "Form1_Load" and could not find an available extension method "Form1_Load" that accepts type "Form1" as the first argument (perhaps a missing using directive or assembly reference).

How to fix this?

I need the program to just work

Comment: Well presumably somewhere in the designer you've specified that a method called `Form1_Load` should handle the `Load` event, but you haven't got such a method. So either add the method, or remove the handler in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you posted means that there is no **Form1_Load** method inside your Form1. To fix that problem, Check the event subscription. Make sure that the "Form1_Load" event is subscribed properly. In the same file where the "Form1_Load" method is defined, check for code that subscribes to the event. It should look like this:

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
```

either you  need to delete that event handler generated code or make a Form1_Load event:

```
Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
// Your code here!
}
```